# Robot arm manipulation library

Tags: c#, object-oriented, serial-port, mechatronics

I have created a DLL library that controls an robotic arm. Could you tell me if my design is correct? The robot communicates over serial port. The code works but I would like to receive a feedback regarding the design as I don't have enough experience.

Robot (`uArm`) is moving cards from one bin to another. I have the following classes:

- `uArm`
- `uArmCommands` (and `IuArmCommands`)
- `SerialPortConnector`
- `MyConfig`

and a .config file.

**`uArm`**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Library to control the robotic arm made by evol.net with firmware made by HID
    /// </summary>
    public class uArm
    {
        #region Logging
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(uArm));
        #endregion

        private static bool hasCard = false;
        private MyConfig myConfig;
        private IuArmCommands myCommands;

        public uArm()
        {
            InitLogging();
            myConfig = new MyConfig();
            myCommands = new uArmCommands(myConfig.COMPort);
            log.Info("Creating a new uArm Robot");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method checks if the provided bin is empty or not
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="PositionID">PositionID of the bin to check</param>
        /// <returns>If the bin has at least 1 card returns true</returns>
        public Boolean BinNotEmpty(String PositionID)
        {
            return myConfig.BinNotEmpty(PositionID);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method that moves the arm to the specified bin and takes one card.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="PositionID">Name of the bin from the dll config file</param>
        /// <returns>true if success</returns>
        public bool TakeCardFromBin(String PositionID)
        {

            bool result = false;
            // checking if the robot doesn't have any card already and if the bin is not empty
            try
            {
                if (!hasCard && myConfig.positionSection.Positions.getByPositionID(PositionID).Cards > 0)
                {
                    result = GoToPosition(myConfig.positionSection.Positions.getByPositionID(PositionID));
                    if (result)
                        result = myCommands.runPump();
                    if (result)
                    {
                        hasCard = true;
                        myConfig.positionSection.Positions.getByPositionID(PositionID).Cards--;
                        myConfig.SaveConfig();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                log.Error("Robot couldn't take a card from a bin");
                throw new Exception("Robot couldn't take a card from a bin");
            }

            //go down
            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method that moves the arm to the specified bin nad releases the card.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="PositionID">Name of the bin from the dll config file</param>
        /// <returns>true if success</returns>
        public bool ReturnCardToBin(String PositionID)
        {
            bool result = false;
            // checking if the robot really has a card.
            if (hasCard)
            {
                try
                {
                    result = GoToPosition(myConfig.positionSection.Positions.getByPositionID(PositionID));
                    if (result)
                        result = myCommands.offPump();
                    if (result)
                    {
                        hasCard = false;
                        myConfig.positionSection.Positions.getByPositionID(PositionID).Cards++;
                        myConfig.SaveConfig();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    log.Error("Robot couldn't return a card.");
                    throw new Exception("Robot couldn't return a card.");
                }
                //go down
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("Impossible to return a card because the robot doesn't have any card.");
                throw new Exception("Impossible to return a card because the robot doesn't have any card.");
            }
            return result;
        }

        private bool GoToPosition(PositionElement position)
        {
            return myCommands.setPosition(position.Stretch, position.Rotation, position.Height);
        }

        ~uArm()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            myCommands.offPump();
            myCommands.reset();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

    }
```

**`IuArmCommands`**

```
interface IuArmCommands
{
    bool getPos();
    bool offPump();
    bool pinch();
    bool releasePinch();
    bool reset();
    bool runBeeper();
    bool runPump();
    bool setHeight(int value);
    bool setPosition(int stretch, int rotation, int height);
    bool setRotation(int value);
    bool setStretch(int value);
    bool setVelocity(int value);
    bool setVelocityRot(int value);
    bool setVelocityWrist(int value);
    bool setWrist(int value);
    bool toggleDebug();
}
```

uArmCommands

```
public class uArmCommands : IuArmCommands
    {
        private SerialPortConnector mySerialPortConnector;
        public uArmCommands(String COMPort)
        {
            mySerialPortConnector  = new SerialPortConnector(COMPort);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that combines all the necessary movements to go to x,y,z position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stretch"></param>
        /// <param name="rotation"></param>
        /// <param name="height"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool setPosition(int stretch, int rotation, int height)
        {
            bool result = false;
            result = setStretch(stretch);
            if(result)
                setRotation(rotation);
            if(result)
                setHeight(height);
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Stretch Position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">0 to 210</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool setStretch(int value)
        {
            if (rangeCheck(0, 210, value))
                return mySerialPortConnector.Write("S" + value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Height Position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">150(highest) to -180(lowest)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool setHeight(int value)
        {
            if (rangeCheck(-180, 150, value))
                return mySerialPortConnector.Write("H" + value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set Rotation Position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">-90 to 90</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool setRotation(int value)
        {
            if (rangeCheck(-90, 90, value))
                return mySerialPortConnector.Write("R" + value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the wrist twist
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">-90 to 90</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool setWrist(int value)
        {
            if (rangeCheck(-90, 90, value))
                return mySerialPortConnector.Write("W" + value);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
        }

        public bool reset()
        {
            return mySerialPortConnector.Write("!");
        }

        public bool getPos()
        {
            return mySerialPortConnector.Write("?");
        }

        public bool runPump()
        {
            return mySerialPortConnector.Write("P");
        }

        public bool offPump()
        {
            return mySerialPortConnector.Write("O");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the parameter is inside a specified range
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="start"></param>
        /// <param name="stop"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool rangeCheck(int start, int stop, int value)
        {
            if (start <= value && stop >= value)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

**`SerialPortConnector`**

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SerialPortConnector));
        private String _COMPort;
        private SerialPort _serialPort1;
        static string serialBuffer = "";
        static string expectedEcho = null;
        static object expectedEchoLock = new object();
        static ManualResetEvent expectedEchoReceived = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public SerialPortConnector(String ComPort)
        {
            _COMPort = ComPort;
            OpenPort(_COMPort);
        }

        ~SerialPortConnector()
        {
            ClosePort();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Setting connection parameters and opening serial port.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="COM"></param>
        public void OpenPort(String COM)
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
                // setting serial port connection parameters
                _serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 1000;
                _serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                _serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
                _serialPort1.PortName = COM;
                _serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
                _serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
                _serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "1");
                _serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                _serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                log.Error("Unable to open serial port: " + _COMPort);
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to open serial port.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that reads from serial port.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (_serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_serialPort1.BytesToRead];
                int bytesRead = _serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead <= 0) return;
                serialBuffer += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                string[] lines = serialBuffer.Split('\r', '\n');
                // Don't process the last part, because it's not terminated yet
                for (int i = 0; i < (lines.Length - 1); i++)
                {
                    if (lines[i].Length > 0)
                        ProcessLine(lines[i]);
                }
                serialBuffer = lines[lines.Length - 1]; // keep last part
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to precess serial port message
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="line"></param>
        public void ProcessLine(string line)
        {

            bool unsolicitedMessageReceived = false;
            lock (expectedEchoLock)
            {
                if (line == expectedEcho)
                {
                    expectedEchoReceived.Set();
                }
                else
                {
                    unsolicitedMessageReceived = true;
                }
            }
            if (unsolicitedMessageReceived)
            {
                // Process unsolicited/unexpected messages
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writing to serial port.
        /// After sending a message a lock is made and another thread awaits for the reply.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Write(string input)
        {
            if (!_serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                // if the serial port was closed we try to open it again, 
                // if the open method fails it will throw an exception
                OpenPort(_COMPort);
            }

            string command = string.Empty;
            command = input;
            command = DelSpace(command);

            lock (expectedEchoLock)
            {
                expectedEchoReceived.Reset();
                expectedEcho = "K";
            }

            SendAsHex(command);
            return expectedEchoReceived.WaitOne(5000); // timeout after 5 seconds

        }

        private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

        private void SendAsHex(string str)
        {
            _serialPort1.Write(GetBytes(str), 0, GetBytes(str).Length);
        }

        private string DelSpace(string str)
        {
            string TempStr = string.Empty;
            int Len = str.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] != ' ')
                    TempStr += str[i];
            }
            Len = TempStr.Length;
            if (Len % 2 != 0)
                TempStr = '0' + TempStr;
            return TempStr;
        }

        public void ClosePort()
        {
            _serialPort1.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MyConfigSection" type="Robots.uArm.MyConfigSection, Robots.uArm" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="COMPort" value="COM3"/>
  </appSettings>
  <MyConfigSection>
    <Positions>
      <Position PositionID="bin1" Type="bin" Stretch="100" Rotation="-50" Height="100" Twist="0" Cards="10" />
      <Position PositionID="bin2" Type="bin" Stretch="100" Rotation="50" Height="100" Twist="0" Cards="0"/>
    </Positions>
  </MyConfigSection>
</configuration>
```

**Example of use**

```
uArm myRobot = new uArm();
while (myRobot.BinNotEmpty("bin1"))
{
    myRobot.TakeCardFromBin("bin1");
    myRobot.ReturnCardToBin("bin2");
}
myRobot.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Naming**

Base on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. That being said, the `IuArmCommands` interface should look like so

```
interface IuArmCommands
{
    bool GetPos();
    bool OffPump();
    bool Pinch();
    bool ReleasePinch();
    bool Reset();
    bool RunBeeper();
    bool RunPump();
    bool SetHeight(int value);
    bool SetPosition(int stretch, int rotation, int height);
    bool SetRotation(int value);
    bool SetStretch(int value);
    bool SetVelocity(int value);
    bool SetVelocityRot(int value);
    bool SetVelocityWrist(int value);
    bool SetWrist(int value);
    bool ToggleDebug();
}
```

One of the important aspects in naming is to be consistent with your naming style. You are mixing a lot of styles throughout your classes.

Some examples of class variables

```
private IuArmCommands myCommands;
private String _COMPort;
private SerialPort _serialPort1;
```

For class level variables you are using 3 different styles. You use `camelCase` casing, underscore + `PascalCase` casing and underscore + `camelCase` casing.

You really should stick to one style only.

The same is true for variables you use in your methods.

Some examples of method variables

```
bool unsolicitedMessageReceived = false;
string TempStr = string.Empty;
```

again you are mixing `PascalCase` casing (which shouldn't be used for variables) and `camelCase` casing.

Based on the same naming guidelines method parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing, which your parameters do, but unfortunately not always.

Naming is a pretty hard field in our job, but doing it correctly will make the code easier to maintain and read. This doesn't mean that the C# naming guideline should be the bible for naming, but it helps a lot to have some kind of naming guidelines which then should be mandatory.

Also the names of methods and variables should be well choosen, so **Bob the maintainer**  can see at first glance what they are about. This involves also that one shouldn't use abbreviations like `GetPos()` which would be better named like `GetArmPosition()` or `GetPosition()`. This is also true if you have a method named `SetPosition()` so **Bob** would expect a `GetPosition()` rather than a `GetPos()`.

Speaking about `GetPos()` I think it is rather strange that this method returns a `bool`.

I also don't understand why you have prefixed all the classes with **u** like `uArm`. What does the `u` stand for. A more descriptive name could be `RobotArm` which again tells **Bob** what the class is about.

---

This

> ```
> throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
> ```

should be changed to throw the correct exception. Do you know that in C# you can throw an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

---

A construct like

```
if (condition)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

can be simplified like

```
return condition;
```

So your `rangeCheck()` method

> ```
> private bool rangeCheck(int start, int stop, int value)
> {
>     if (start <= value && stop >= value)
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> }
> ```

should look like so ( see also the `PascalCase` casing for the method name)

```
private bool RangeCheck(int start, int stop, int value)
{
    return start <= value && stop >= value;
}
```

---

You have a lot of magic numbers in your code. These numbers should be extracted to meaningful constants.

A well named constant will tell you in a month or in a year, if you look at your code again,  more than e.g the number itself. Also for **Bob** it isn't obvious what the numbers in e.g

> ```
> public bool setStretch(int value)
> {
>     if (rangeCheck(0, 210, value))
>         return mySerialPortConnector.Write("S" + value);
>     else
>         throw new ArgumentException("Value outside of range.");
> }
> ```

mean.

Speaking about this method, I need to tell you that the xml documentation

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set Stretch Position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">0 to 210</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
```

tells one more than the method name, which isn't that good. Naming this method `SetStretchPosition()` would have been better.

---

I would like to encourage you to **always**  use barces `{}` also if it is only a single statement for an `if` or `else`. Using braces will make your code less error prone.

---

Comment: I am using the **u** prefix (`uArm`) as it is the commercial name of the [Robot](http://store.evol.net/) but you are right that it is messy. I will apply all of your suggestions. 
Besides the naming, the object oriented design looks ok? Would it be better to make `uArm` to inherit from `uArmCommands`? I want all the methods from the interface `IuArmCommands` to be accessible from the library.

Comment: Basically its only a style review. About the library part you need to decide what your `Arm` **should** do. Right now the methods only **use** the IuArmCommands and I guess that is good if you want only to move the cards. You need to be aware about consequences if you want to alter the behaviour. I would like to encourage you to sit down with a pen and paper designing your library by hand first. Think about possibilities / extensions you may want to be included. Think about problems which could occur.